# Null check operator used on a null value instagram clone

Tags: flutter, dart

[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Answer (score 0):

This might have basically happened while parsing json data from server into dart object. The issue basically arises in general whenever the members of the dart class are not nullable in which case they can't be left null at the time of initialisation. Due to which while you use the fromJson factory or function the value assigned to this parameter doesn't have that key available in it as a consequence you receive this error.

This could also arise while using named pushing of routes via arguments.

Comment: Possible the solution is:
1. Cross check the key assigned is it named correctly or not.
2. Or make the parameter nullable.